# How to configure a SQLite database for use in a Flask app

Tags: html, web, flask

I'm developing a web app, and I need to know how to configure a SQLite database.

I used `db = SQL("sqlite:///database.db")` where SQL is a private function from school. I can't access the definition, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use sqlite3 package from python  standard library ?

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
```

Here's the link for python 3.7 : https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html